# Plotly animation speed : Faster than duration 0

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plot with only one line of 6500 points
Above this line I have a marker that is animated following the line, like we can see in this example : [Intro to animations in Python](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#moving-point-on-a-curve)

Everything is working great, when I press play, the point starts to move along the line. But my issue is the speed. I need to make it as fast as the real data recorded.

I have set the frame duration and the transition duration to 0 but still it is not fast enough !

```
# Buttons
    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus=[dict(buttons = [dict(label="Play",
                                method="animate",
                                args=[None, {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False}, "mode": "immediate", "transition": {"duration": 0}}])],
                                type='buttons',
                                showactive=False,
                                y=1,
                                x=1.12,
                                xanchor='right',
                                yanchor='top')])
```

[image]

How can I make this even faster ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you generating your animation frames ? Can you add the relevant code ?